# Not Able to append the documents retrieved

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am not able to append the documents retrieved from the Firestore database in chat application based on Swift IOS to the "messages" variable, after appending I have configure the table cells as below in the code, I am getting the following error
Error

```
Cannot convert value of type '[QueryDocumentSnapshot]' to expected argument type 'DocumentSnapshot'
```

Code

```
    var messages: [DocumentSnapshot]! = []
          func configuredatabase ()
    {
    db.collection("messages").document("hello").collection("newmessages").document("2").collection("hellos").document("K").collection("messages").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
                    guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                        print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
                        return
                    }

//here is the error
          self.messages.append(documents)

        }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Dequeue cell
    let cell = self.clientTable .dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViewCell", for: indexPath)
    // Unpack message from Firebase DataSnapshot
    let messageSnapshot = self.messages![indexPath.row]
    guard let message = messageSnapshot as? [String:String] else { return cell }
    let name = message[Constants.MessageFields.name] ?? ""
    if let imageURL = message[Constants.MessageFields.imageURL] {
      if imageURL.hasPrefix("gs://") {
        Storage.storage().reference(forURL: imageURL).getData(maxSize: INT64_MAX) {(data, error) in
          if let error = error {
            print("Error downloading: \(error)")
            return
          }
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage.init(data: data!)
            cell.setNeedsLayout()
          }
        }
      } else if let URL = URL(string: imageURL), let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL) {
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage.init(data: data)
      }
      cell.textLabel?.text = "sent by: \(name)"
    } else {
      let text = message[Constants.MessageFields.text] ?? ""
      cell.textLabel?.text = name + ": " + text
      cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "ic_account_circle")
      if let photoURL = message[Constants.MessageFields.photoURL], let URL = URL(string: photoURL),
          let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL) {
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data)
      }
    }
    return cell
  }
```

Comment: you are trying to append `QueryDocumentSnapshot ` to `DocumentSnapshot`.

Comment: The method you are using to append the documents to an array takes a single element. You should be using this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126939-append

Comment: @SureshMopidevi yes, I know it is not possible, actually I referred the example of friendlychats of code lab which is based on realtime database, and then I converted the database schema to the Firestore database, now I am stuck at this

Comment: checkout my answer

Answer (score 0):

While there are two other very good answers, there may be some confusion between a

```
FIRDocumentSnapshot   (Note: renamed to DocumentSnapshot)
```

Which is returned when you want to get a specific document: someDoc.getDocument(

and

```
FIRQuerySnapshot  (Note: renamed to QuerySnapshot)
```

Which is returned when an observer is added to a collection or a series of documents is being retrieved: someCollection.getDocuments and then each document within QuerySnapshot is a discreet FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot (renamed to QueryDocumentSnapshot). (e.g. iterate over the QuerySnapshot to get the child QueryDocumentSnapshot)

Note that DocumentSnapshot may return nil in data property if the document doesn't exists, so it can be tested for .exists. Whereas QueryDocumentSnapshot will never be nil (exists is always true) because deleted data is not returned.

In the question, an observer is being added to a collection with

```
.collection("messages").addSnapshotListener
```

therefore the data returned is a QuerySnapshot and to store it as a var, the var type would need to match

```
var messagesQuerySnapshot: QuerySnapshot!
```

and then inside the listener

```
db.collection("messages")...addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
   messagesQuerySnapshot = querySnapshot
```

However, I would not recommend that.

I would suggest a messages class that can be initialize with the data retrieved from Firestore and store those in an array.

```
class MessagesClass {
   var msg_id = ""
   var msg = ""
   var from = ""

   convenience init(withQueryDocSnapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot) {
      //init vars from the document snapshot
   }
}
```

and then a class var datasource array to hold them

```
var messagesArray = [MessageClass]()
```

and then code to read the messages, create the message objects and add them to the dataSource array

```
db.collection("messages")...getDocuments { querySnapshot, error in
   guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
      print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
      return
   }

   for doc in snapshot.documents {
      let aMsg = MessageClass(withQueryDocSnapshot: doc)
      self.messagesArray.append(aMsg)
   }
}
```

NOTE: we are not adding an listener here, we are getting the documents one time. If you want to add a listener to watch for users being added, changed or removed, additional code is needed to detect the changes.

See the Firebase Documentation on [Viewing Changes Between Snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots)

Answer (score -1):

Replace `self.messages.append(documents)` with `self.messages.append(contentsOf: documents)`

The first method takes a single element and the second one takes a collection which is in your case.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126937-append
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126939-append

Comment: This would not be correct. Because a listener is added, any time a message is added, changed or removed, ALL of the messages will be re-added to the array. So for example if the array contained message_0 and message_1, and then later message_2 was added to Firestore, the array would then contains [message_0, message_1, message_0, message_1, message_2] etc.

Answer (score -1):

```swift
var messages: [[String: Any]] = []

db.collection("messages").document("hello").collection("newmessages").document("2").collection("hellos").document("K").collection("messages").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
    guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
        print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
        return
    }

    for doc in documents {
        self.messages.append(doc.data())
    }
}
```

Comment: You can append to the `messages` array or you can create a message model and decode from document data. This library is handy to decode timestamps without pain https://www.github.com/alickbass/CodableFirebase.

Comment: QueryDocumentSnapshot inherits from DocumentSnapshot, you can just append the object. Also there is no need for a for loop, there is a method for it.

Comment: This answer would not be correct as every time a message is added, changed or removed, ALL of the messages would be appended to messages array. Also, using this route you also loose the documentID of each message so if it needs to be deleted, marked as read etc, you would not have direct access to the documentID